# Find index of tag with certain text in beautifulsoup/python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a simple 4x2 html table that contains information about a property.

I'm trying to extract the value `1972`, which is under the column heading of `Year Built`. If I find all the tags `td`, how do I extract the index of the tag that contains the text `Year Built`?

Because once I find that index, I can just add `4` to get to the tag that contains the value `1972`.

Here is the html:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Building</td>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Year Built</td>
            <td>Sq. Ft.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>R01</td>
            <td>DWELL</td>
            <td>1972</td>
            <td>1166</td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

For example I know that if my input is index `2` and my output is text of that tag `Year Built`, I can just do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(myhtml)
td_list = soup.find_all('td')
print td_list[2].text
```

But how do I use input of text `Year Built` to get output of index `2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your table has a static scheme, it is better using row and column indexes. Try this:

```
rows = soup.find("table").find("tbody").find_all("tr")
print rows[1].find_all("td")[2].get_text()
```

Alternatively if you just want to find index number of the tag containing "Year Built":

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(myhtml)
td_list = soup.find_all('td')
i = 0
for elem in td_list:
    if elem.text == 'Year Built':
        ind = i
    i += 1
print td_list[ind].text
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert it to dict and get the value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
table_data = [[cell.text for cell in row("td")] for row in BeautifulSoup(myhtml)("tr")]
dict = dict(zip(table_data[0], table_data[1]))
print dict['Year Built']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your content is stored in filename.
Please try:

```
In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(open("filename"))
In [4]: print soup.find_all('td')[2].string
Year Built
```